# expected constructor, destructor, or type conversation before '(' token

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I'm new to the world of programming and Arduinos and I am not really sure how to solve this error message. Been researching for answers for quite some time now and I still cannot find an answer as to how to solve this error message. There are error messages on the Arduino IDE and suggestions are also given but I'm not sure how to use those suggestions. I am using an Arduino Pro Micro for this project.

```js
#include <Joystick.h>

//initializing variables 

int R2 = 2;
int L3 = 3;

//Define input pins  
#define joyX A0
#define joyY A1
#define joyX A2
#define joyY A3
#define joyButton1 2
#define joyButton2 3

//Joystick(Joystick HID ID, Joytstick Type, Button Count, Hat Switch Count, Include X, Include Y, Include Z,
//Include Rx, Include Ry, Include Rudder, Include Throttle, Include Accelerator, Include Break, Include Steering 

Joystick_Joystick(0x04, JOYSTICK_TYPE_JOYSTICK, 3, 0, true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);

//initializing bool constant 

const bool initAutoSendState = true;

//initializing axis

int xAxis_ = 0;
int yAxis_ = 0;

//Set Button Default State
  int lastButtonState =0;
  int lastButtonState =0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(joyButton1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(joyButton2, INPUT_PULLUP):

  Joystick.begin();
}

void loop() {
//Axis Runtime
    xAxis_ = analogRead(joyX);
    xAxis_ = map (xAxis,0,1023,0,255);
    Joystick.setXAxis(xAxis_);
    yAxis_ = analogRead(joyY);
    yAxis_ = map (yAxis,0,1023,0,255);
    Joystick.setYAxis(yAxis_);

//Button State setup 
  int currentButton1State = !digitalRead(joyButton1);
    if (currentButton1State != lastButton1State) {
    Joystick.setButton (0, currentButton1State);
    lastButton1State = currentButton1State;
    }

  int currentButton2State = !digitalRead(joyButton2);
    if (currentButton2State != lastButton2State) {
    Joystick.setButton (0, currentButton2State);
    lastButton2State = currentButton2State;
    }

//Poll Delay/Debounce 
delay(500);
}
```

Comment: This looks very strange to me: `Joystick_Joystick(...)`  Maybe we need `Joystick joystick(...)` instead?  (a space, not an underscore) (and then when it gets used it will be `joystick`) Also, you have two globals called `lastButtonState`. You redefine `joyX` and `joyY`. In the loop, you set joystick button 0 both times.

Comment: Ha, well I found the correct documents too late... It looks like we keep the underscore, but we still need the space:  `Joystick_ Joystick( ... )`  Maybe the examples would have helped out with that? Also it would have helped if you said which joystick library it was (and a link). But, I think this will fix it! :-)

Comment: https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary

that was where the library for the joystick is, and the issue or the error is on this part of the code: Joystick_ Joystick( ... ) still not sure how to fix this part, but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @aMike I really appreciate your help. This is my first time asking questions online.

Comment: To fix it, insert a space between the underscore and the second Joystick on the line where Joystick is declared and defined. At least I think that will do it. Change `Joystick_Joystick` to this `Joystick_ Joystick`  Look closely at the examples for that library (some menu item / Examples / Joystick / etc -- hopefully!)